# How to reflect any changes in the application on all activities when using tabs in the application?

Tags: android, tabs

I have a `TabActivity` in android application, and one `tab` changes the `shared preferences` value, but the changes happened in one tab can't be seen by the other tabs util I run all the application again, how can the changed values in the application and shared between all `tabs` can be visible to all tabs ?